# Pen and tablet digital input on windows form application

Tags: vb.net

In my vb.net project (visual basic 2008) I need to store a **signature** in an image format (preferably .png format), amusing pen/tablet hardware is available to use such as a wacom bamboo tablet (the one I'm using) how would the customers' signature be transferred from the digital pen/tablet and put into a picture box on a windows form. The image will be stored in a file structure and will be referred to through it's own path ex. (c://sig1.png) the path will be stored as a string as part of the users record.

Factors such as pixel height and width will have to be taken into account to avoid stretching and disproportions.

I found it quite hard to explain this in text, please ask questions if unsure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch the computer.
2. Plug the tablet device after the OS loaded.
3. Open Photoshop and configure the device (prior buy and install photoshop if not available)
4. Add a new (empty layer) and delete the (white) background one.
5. Ask a custommer to sign.
6. Save the file as PNG in the directory of your choice.
7. In VS 2008, use an `OpenFileDialog` to find the saved PNG.
8. `YourPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(TheFileOpener.FileName).Clone()`
9. Click on an added `Button` which code embeds the File in a file structure or save TheFileOpener.FileName value in your custommer record (didn't really understood that part of the explanation)

Errrr. Okay ! that wasn't nice of me. Sorry :P But I highly doubt there is someone here to...

- write the entire code to configure and monitor the inputs from your Wacom device
- interpret the inputs and draw a Bitmap (System.Drawing with Graphics ? Array of Byte and Marshall.Copy ?) taking account of X and Y resolution...

Of course, if your device handle the bitmap part, then just do :

```
MyPictureBox.Image = TheBitmapFromDevice
MyPictureBox.Image.Save(FilePath, FileFormat.PNG)
```

Good Luck !
Hint : You should have started to look at Wacom API first, then, come here to ask for help on a specific issue...

Comment: The steps you described first of all I already have in place xD. Im looking for a better way. I am just after a method of doing it, rather than a solution.